# pass attribute to child rule in boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have two rules with the same attribute.

Is it possible to pass the attribute of the matrix_ rule to the matrixBlock_ child rule?
I want to keep the repeat directive from creating an attribute of the form vector< >. Instead it should just keep writing into the attribute of matrix_ (numBlocks's times).
I tried to pass the attribute as inherited attribute to the child rule and it compiles(see below). But I get several "ghost" entries in my vector which come not from the phoenix::push_back.
Also this seems not to be the optimal way for me. Is it possible to us automatic attribute propagation in matrixBlock_ instead of semantic actions?

```
typedef vector<columnT> Matrix;
matrix_ = repeat(numBlocks)[ matrixBlock_(_val) ];
matrixBlock_ = *column[phoenix::push_back(_r1, _1)];

qi::rule<Iterator, Matrix(), ascii::space_type> matrix_;
qi::rule<Iterator, void(Matrix&), ascii::space_type> matrixBlock_;
```

---

### Update

to clarify the question:

if I write the rule with no semantic actions the synthesized attribute of matrix_ would be

```
vector< vector< columnT > >
```

-

```
typedef vector<columnT> Matrix;
matrix_ = repeat(numBlocks)[ matrixBlock_ ];
matrixBlock_ = *column;

qi::rule<Iterator, Matrix(), ascii::space_type> matrix_;
qi::rule<Iterator, Matrix(), ascii::space_type> matrixBlock_;
```

I want it to have the same attribute type as matrixBlock_, a 1-dimansional array.

---

my actual solution is to use only one rule. (looks to easy :-) )

```
typedef vector<columnT> Matrix;
matrix_ = repeat(numBlocks)[ *column_[ phoenix::push_back(_val, _1) ] ];
//matrixBlock_ = *column;

qi::rule<Iterator, Matrix(), ascii::space_type> matrix_;
//qi::rule<Iterator, Matrix(), ascii::space_type> matrixBlock_;
```

---

### Update

I was able to reproduce the the phantom entries with this code in vs2010 and boost 1.46.1

http://liveworkspace.org/code/505091dc4631a379763567168a728e0c

> output was: 42, 45, -9, 3, 2, 1, 12, 34, 56, 0, 0, 0

My mistake was using an old Boost version. There are no phontoms with 1.5.

Now I have two working versions of my grammar. Is it possible to redesign the grammar without the use of the push_back semantic action?

Comment: Could you review/edit the question title? I have a feeling it doesn't accurately reflect the actual question

Comment: I'm unable to see what you are asking here. Could you just show a working example? See http://sscce.org/ (as an example, take the ***two*** SSCCE's from my existing example, perhaps)

Comment: Thanks for the sample. The answer was surprisingly simple now

Comment: more or less surprisingly your answer does not work with boost 1_46_1...

Comment: Yes, this was improved in V2.5 - boost 1_47 **[Change note](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/what_s_new/spirit_2_4.html)**: `"The attribute handling for container attributes of sequences and container components (list, Kleene, Plus, and repeat) has been completely rewritten. It now supports many more use cases and behaves much more predictable than the older version. Thanks to Thomas Taylor, Richard Crossley, Semen, Adalberto Castelo, and many others for reporting bugs and helping in making the new code behave as expected."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Updated

Answering your edited question: Yes you can do this without semantic actions, doing simply:

```
template<typename It>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, Matrix(), qi::space_type>
{
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(matrix_)
    {
        matrixBlock_ = qi::lit(";") >> *qi::int_;
        matrix_      = qi::repeat(3)[ matrixBlock_ ];
    }
    qi::rule<It, Matrix(), qi::space_type> matrixBlock_, matrix_;
};
```

Note that you *may* want to validate the number of rows/columns. **[See my extended sample](http://liveworkspace.org/code/d4b5c68b584b4ce494e4c2b91c1fbcb2)**, which uses an extra semantic action to check that (note the subtle change from `*int_` to `+int_` to avoid empty rows):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

typedef std::vector<int> Matrix;

template<typename It>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, Matrix(), qi::space_type>
{
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(matrix_)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        matrixBlock_ = lit(";") >> +int_ >> eps( 0 == (phx::size(_val) % 3));
        matrix_      = repeat(3)[ matrixBlock_ ];
    }
    qi::rule<It, Matrix(), qi::space_type> matrixBlock_, matrix_;
};

int main()
{
    std::string test = ";42 45 -9; 3 2 1; 12 34 56";

    std::string::const_iterator f(test.begin()), l(test.end());

    Parser<std::string::const_iterator> parser;
    Matrix m;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(f,l,parser,qi::space, m))
        std::cout << "Wokay\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "Uhoh\n";

    std::cout << karma::format(karma::auto_ % ", ", m) << "\n";
}
```

---

*Old answer*:

Yes, you can use Spirit's *customization points* to treat your user-defined type as a container. The documentation entry I'd suggest for this is here:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/is_container.html

Here is a simple example showing how to use it, live:

- **http://liveworkspace.org/code/2d708ecb64ad6fbf9708c203f26965ce**

> **Side note** with regards to 'phantom entries', in general:
>
> Note that there is a bit of a FAQ related to backtracking grammars and container attributes. The thing is, for performance reasons, parsers won't undo ('rollback') changes to their underlying containers on backtracking. You can force this behaviour using [`qi::hold`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/hold.html) but it may worth the effort to redesign the grammar to either
>
> - avoid backtracking or
> - commit to the attribute at a later stage (using semantic actions)

Full code sample:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

struct Matrix
{
   std::vector<int> data;
};

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
   template <>
      struct is_container<Matrix>
      {
      };

   template <typename Attrib>
      struct push_back_container<Matrix, Attrib>
      {
         static bool call(Matrix& c, Attrib const& val)
         {
            c.data.push_back(val);
            return true;
         }
      };

   template <>
      struct container_value<Matrix>
      {
         typedef int type;
      };
} } }

template<typename It>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, Matrix(), qi::space_type>
{
   Parser() : Parser::base_type(start)
   {
      start = *qi::int_;
   }
   qi::rule<It, Matrix(), qi::space_type> start;
};

int main()
{
   std::string test = "42 45 -9";

   std::string::const_iterator f(test.begin()),
      l(test.end());

   Parser<std::string::const_iterator> parser;
   Matrix m;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(f,l,parser,qi::space, m))
      std::cout << "Wokay\n";
   else
      std::cerr << "Uhoh\n";

   std::cout << karma::format(karma::auto_ % ", ", m.data) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Wokay
42, 45, -9
```

---

#### Update

A little more background:

Of course, for a trivial example like this, that just wraps a standard supported container type, it would be fairly easy to employ fusion *adaptation* instead: ( http://liveworkspace.org/code/56aea8619867451a21cd49fddb1e93bd )

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

struct Matrix { std::vector<int> data; }; 
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Matrix, (std::vector<int>, data));

int main()
{
    std::string test = "42 45 -9";
    std::string::const_iterator f(test.begin()), l(test.end());

    Matrix m;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(f,l, qi::eps >> *qi::int_, qi::space, m))
        std::cout << karma::format(karma::auto_ % ", ", m.data) << "\n";
}
```

*Note that the `qi::eps` is necessary due to a bug (AFAICT) with structs that contain only one data element. See e.g. [discussion here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/BOOST-FUSION-ADAPT-STRUCT-with-single-entry-td2675332.html#a2675334) (and some other mentions)*

Comment: Edited in the links since [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/) is up again. Also added background showing the usual alternative for completeness

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. I don't see how this solves my problem atm. I clarified the question a little.