# Boost::Spirit::QI parser: index of parsed element

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Is it possible (using Boost::Spirit::QI) to parse numbers from a comma separated string so that I get the index of each parsed number?

Suppose I have a string `"23,123,65,1"` and I want to insert each of these numbers into a matrix at given locations (0, 1, 2, 3). One way to do it would to parse the numbers into an std::vector and then copy them to the matrix row, but it isn't particularly fast.

Currently I'm using the vector variant:

```
Matrix data(10, 4);
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
std::string str = "23,123,65,1";
std::vector<double> res;
if (qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), qi::double_ % ',', res))
{
  std::for_each(res.begin(), res.end(), [&col, &data, &row](double elem) {

      data(row, col) = elem;
      col++;
});
}
```

It'd be awesome if the parser had a success callback that takes a lambda function or a similar feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a number of approaches.

- What I'd usually recommend instead, is using well thought out `repeat(n)` expressions with directly exposed *container attributes* (like `vector<vector<double> >`).
- What you *seem* to be looking for is semantic actions with state. (This is common practice coming from lex/yacc).

**I treat these approaches in three full demos below** (1., 2. and 3.)

- An advanced technique is using *customization points* to allow Spirit to directly treat your `Matrix` type as a container attribute and override the insertion logic for it using `spirit::traits`. For this approach I refer to this answer: [pass attribute to child rule in boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520649/pass-attribute-to-child-rule-in-boost-spirit/12527010#12527010).

### Using [*inherited attributes*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html)

Here is a relatively straightforward approach:

1. parsing directly into a `vector<vector<double> >` (**[full code live online](http://liveworkspace.org/code/b37f3239dea7ca469e84b77c51eee8dd)**)

   ```
   qi::rule<It, Matrix::value_type(size_t cols), qi::blank_type> row;
   qi::rule<It, Matrix(size_t rows,size_t cols), qi::blank_type> matrix;

   row    %= skip(char_(" \t,")) [ repeat(_r1) [ double_ ] ];
   matrix %= eps // [ std::cout << phx::val("debug: ") << _r1 << ", " << _r2 << "\n" ]
          >> repeat(_r1) [ row(_r2) >> (eol|eoi) ];
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   if (qi::phrase_parse(f,l,parser(10, 4),qi::blank, m))
       std::cout << "Wokay\n";
   else
       std::cerr << "Uhoh\n";
   ```
2. Similarly, but adapting a `Matrix` struct (**[full code live here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/5ae234c5644337de7afef2a492243636)**)

   ```
   struct Matrix
   {
       Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : _cells(), _rows(rows), _cols(cols) { }

       double       & data(size_t col, size_t row)       { return _cells.at(row).at(col); } 
       const double & data(size_t col, size_t row) const { return _cells.at(row).at(col); } 

       size_t columns() const { return _cols; }
       size_t rows()    const { return _rows; }

       std::vector<std::vector<double> > _cells;
       size_t _rows, _cols;
   };

   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Matrix, (std::vector<std::vector<double> >,_cells))
   ```

   Usage

   ```
   Matrix m(10, 4);

   if (qi::phrase_parse(f,l,parser(m.rows(),m.columns()),qi::blank, m))
       std::cout << "Wokay\n";
   else
       std::cerr << "Uhoh\n";
   ```

#### Using semantic actions/qi::locals

**3.** This is more work, but potentially more flexible. You'd define a polymorphic callable type to insert a value at a given cell:

```
struct MatrixInsert
{
    template <typename, typename, typename, typename> struct result { typedef bool type; };
    template <typename Matrix, typename Row, typename Col, typename Value>
        bool operator()(Matrix &m, Row& r, Col& c, Value v) const
        {
            if (r < m.rows() && c < m.columns())
            {
                m.data(r, c++) = v;
                return true; // parse continues
            }
            return false;    // fail the parse
        }
};

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_CALLABLE(matrix_insert, MatrixInsert, 4)
```

The last line makes this a `phoenix` lazy function, so you can use it without weird bind syntax in your semantic actions:

```
qi::rule<It, Matrix(), qi::blank_type, qi::locals<size_t /*_a: row*/, size_t/*_b: col*/> > matrix;
matrix = eps    [ _a = 0 /*current row*/ ]
     >> (
            eps     [ _b = 0 /*current col*/ ] 
         >> double_ [ _pass = matrix_insert(_val, _a, _b, _1) ] % ','
        ) % (eol    [ ++_a /*next row*/])
     ;
```

Full code is, again **[live on liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9b2817f5f6dcf0e0a8d0f024bd96cb9b)**

Comment: Are you a wizard? The third option was exactly what I needed, I had no idea you could do something like that (it works superbly with Eigen's matrices). Wish there was an option to upvote you multiple times. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I enjoy exercising my C++ fu on SO :)

Comment: And just in case you'd be interested - your version sped up the code 2.6x!

Comment: Whoa. I can only imagine that is because previously you had to do a lot of copying around :)

Comment: @gnzlbg that is sad :( I'm pretty confident that the snippets capture the essential bits though