# how to derive abstract source tree in terms of boost::spririt?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, abstract-syntax-tree, boost-spirit-qi

What additional data structures should be organized in order to take the first derivative of an abstract source tree (for string math expression)? Let's say, we have a tree for the string expression, which was built using `boost::spirit`. I.e each node have appropriate `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`/`BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_TPL_STRUCT` definition. So, how to store an additional produced data `struct`-s to each node of primary AST and how they should be constructed?

I think, that they should be constructed via `std::reference_wrapper< T const & >` or `boost::optional< T const & >` to the fields (of type `T`) of original `struct`-s with the same layout. And they should form  the arrays/vectors/deques for each node of source tree (where index is equal to `n`-th derivative of corresponding node of source tree). Each tree traverse with "derivator-visitor" should `push_back`s the next expression to each array for each node. In order to establish the correspondence of source nodes to arrays of theirs derivatives we can make they tagged.

Comment: It's hard to follow your sentences.

Comment: A sample speaks a thousand words

Comment: Are you trying to attach "extra" information to AST nodes? Perhaps see [Boost::Spirit::QI parser: index of parsed element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12772075/85371). There are more examples (e.g. the compiler tutorials use `on_error(success,...)` to attach source locations to AST nodes)

Comment: @sehe I know, that I can tag every node, that I want as showed in `annotation.hpp` in **conjure** example. But it's not much easier task.

Comment: @Zaibis You can skip the second part of the question (my own proposal), as it is written to formally comply with the topical rules.

Comment: @sehe `on_error< success >(...)` is correct